# Capturing return type of unmanaged class using C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, marshalling

I have a method in my native dll, that I want to use. The method returns an object of a type that is also in my native dll.I am trying to write a c++/CLI wrapper.

Now,

- Can I get a return value as the object using C++/CLI and how do I do that?
- Can we store and pass the native C++ object?
- Should I need to create my own class resembling the native C++ class?
- How would I marshal a class?

For Example,My native dll has these classes,

```
class X
{
    /* some props and methods. */
};


Class Y
{
    X* someMethod();
};
```

I need to wrap the `someMethod` class using C++/CLI. Will I be able to get the return value in the CLI?

Comment: Search around SO a bit, I believe something like this has been done before... you can wrap your native code into a managed `value class` I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning pointers to C++ objects from an exported function in a DLL is a pretty bad idea.  It is a nasty memory management problem, you'd expect the client code to release the object.  That can only come to a good end when both DLLs use the *exact* same version of the DLL version of the CRT (/MD compile option).  If you can't recompile the native DLL then stop right now, you cannot make it work reliably or you'll have a big maintenance problem in the future.

Anyhoo, you need a wrapper for both classes.  They should resemble this:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include "xandy.h"
#pragma managed(pop)

using namespace System;

namespace something {

    public ref class XWrapper {
        X* mX;
    public:
        XWrapper(X* obj) : mX(obj) {}
        ~XWrapper() { this->!XWrapper(); }
        !XWrapper() {
            // Trouble is here!!!
            delete mX;
        }
    };

    public ref class YWrapper {
        Y* mY;
    public:
        YWrapper() { mY = new Y; }
        ~YWrapper() { this->!YWrapper(); }
        !YWrapper() { delete mY; }
        XWrapper^ someMethod() {
            return gcnew XWrapper(mY->someMethod());
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: IIRC, the Visual C++ /MT option won't let two DLLs share the runtime allocators, as each DLL will have its own statically linked C++ runtime (and thus, allocators). The option should be /MD (and /MDd for debug).